# Custom DocumentFilter - "Invalid remove" Exception

Tags: java, swing

I've created my own DocumentFormat, list of ints separated by semicolons. Parsing String etc. works fine, but problem appears when I want to replace whole text with my new String.

I get Exception `Invalid remove` when calling `super.replace(fb, 0, out.length(), out, attrs);`. Can anybody explain this message?

Here's my class code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class IntsFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
       public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
             AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            // Do nothing so far
       }

       @Override
       public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
             AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

           Boolean test = false;

           try {
               Integer.parseInt(text);
               test = true;
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               test = text.equals(";");
           }

            if (!test) return;

            Document doc = fb.getDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
            sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);

            ArrayList<String> data = toArray(sb.toString());
            System.out.println(arrayToString(data));
            String out = arrayToString(data);

            try {
                super.replace(fb, 0, out.length(), out, attrs);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

       }

       @Override
       public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
             throws BadLocationException {

           try {
               super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
          // TODO: uzupełnić

       }

       protected String arrayToString(ArrayList<String> input) {

           String result = "";

           for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {

               if (i == input.size() - 1)
                   result += input.get(i).equals("0") ? "" : input.get(i);
               else
                   result += input.get(i) + "; ";

           }

           return result;

       }

       protected ArrayList<String> toArray(String input) {

           input = input.replaceAll(";$", "; 0");

           ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

           for (String part : input.replaceAll("\\s", "").split(";")) {
               try {
                   Integer.parseInt(part);
                   list.add(part);
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
           }

           return list;

       }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: A SSCCE is most importantly runnable. It would be nice copy and paste your code, press play (in my IDE) and get the same result as the behaviour in question. So please add a main method, JFrame etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error occurs if the offset + length is greater than the current length of the document.  Don't do the replace yourself.  Let the superclass do it.  Move your super.replace() call to after the test.